# KGraphViewer replacement

Tags: kde, compiling, qt

Is there a replacement package for the deleted KGraphViewer?

The qt dev pacakage is installed. Compilation of the latest Umbrello works.

Also I tried to compile it from the git remake `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local` ..

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt-Version 5.2.1 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4  
-- Found Perl: /usr/bin/perl (found version "5.18.2") 
-- Found Phonon: /usr/include (Required is at least version "4.3.80") 
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY - Success
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/torbjorr/kgraphviewer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed

CMake Error at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:1311 (message):
  Unable to compile a basic Qt application.  Qt has not been found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:95 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/torbjorr/kgraphviewer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/torbjorr/kgraphviewer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: How did you install Qt? Is it from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @Sneetsher Yes, from the Ubuntu repo

Answer (score 0):

**KGraphViewer**

It is: http://extragear.kde.org/apps/kgraphviewer/

Available: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kgraphviewer

Asking backports: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

**DIY - if you want it now**
(from the Utopic to the Trusty)

At here installed:

- build-essential
- fakeroot
- dpkg-dev
- cmake
- debhelper
- kdelibs5-dev
- libphonon-dev

Downloading http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/kgraphviewer :

- kgraphviewer_2.1.90-0ubuntu1.dsc
- kgraphviewer_2.1.90.orig.tar.xz
- kgraphviewer_2.1.90-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz

Unpacking with the command:

```
dpkg-source -x *.dsc
```

Compiling:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc
```

Missing dependencies:

> dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: kdepimlibs5-dev
>   libboost1.55-dev libgraphviz-dev

Installing those and trying again...

There are packages:

- kgraphviewer-dbg_2.1.90-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- kgraphviewer-dev_2.1.90-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- kgraphviewer_2.1.90-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- libkgraphviewer2_2.1.90-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Installing the kgraphviewer and then the libkgraphviewer2.

[image]

Seems to work at here...